# Session for Hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

In my project I have used session for locating a value from a dropdown list via:

```
Session["location"] = worlddrdolist.SelectedItem.Value;
```

And I would like to know if I can use a session for my menu which look like this:

```
<li class="customclass1"><a href="Cateshow.aspx">Computers & Mobiles</a></li>
<li class="customclass1"><a href="Cateshow.aspx" >Factories </a></li>
<li class="customclass1"><a href="Cateshow.aspx" >Games </a></li>
```

What I have to use to make a session store the text in hyperlink: Computers & Mobiles-Factories-Games.

Comment: You want to store the text of the anchor tag into a `Session` variable?

Comment: no, i think he saved it already from a dropdown and want to show the saved session variable in the list element

Comment: @ Nicholas V. in factory, games are stored in my sql database so when the user click on each category of products the he should show the items which has names ex. Games. and if I use hyperlink then the user will not be able to click on the hole box of menu he have to click on the hyperlink text to be able to move to another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="customclass1">
    <a href="~/Cateshow.aspx" 
        title="Computers & Mobiles-Factories-Games" ID="link1"
           runat="server">Computers & Mobiles</a>
</li>
```

Then use FindControl to access the link by ID and store the title attribute contents in Session state.

Alternatively, you could do this:

```
<asp:hyperlink title="Computers & Mobiles-Factories-Games" 
    id="link1" runat="server"></asp:hyperlink>

Session["MyLinkTitle"] = link1.Title;
```

Remember, with a DropDown you have a name and a value and you can use that also.

Comment: The OP wants to store the Text/Caption of the hyperlink, not the link location.

Comment: +1 I just feel like crying and screaming whenever I see this session state use and abuse...